# Can I control access to specific price sets with ACL?

Tags: acl, price-sets

I have two primary member types. Full Members (FM) and Associate Members (AM). I need to keep all the pricing for both groups completely separate and since AM joins to have access to FM, they pay all of the sponsorships and event booth fees. We want to restrict the FM from even seeing those pages. I'm accustomed to Joomla ACL, but the shop I've joined is working in WP, so the ACL seems less fine tuned and I'm not seeing a clear path to manage this task of keeping both groups ignorant of the fees that the other pays.

Where they both register for events, I'm applying an automatic discount for the FM group, but I'm not clear how to essentially create a category or tag that restricts access to only one group. Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Does this extension help? https://civicrm.org/extensions/group-based-pricing

Comment: I think it will. The client is getting a taste of CiviCRM for the first time, having abandoned a custom project that never worked. I have some new instructions which will change my approach to the problem, but I really appreciate the help. I've uncovered that extension since asking the question.